# Xcode not showing console output; How do you flush the console?

Tags: c++, xcode, console, flush

I have a simple C++ program that uses cout and printf to log stuff and it is only showing at the end when the program is closed but if I'm stepping through the program using debug nothing is shown. Did anybody have this problem?

Comment: Quite funny, that you are asking help to do someone else's homework. You should at least add the `homework` tag to the question... Have you even tried googling for `flush` and `console` and `c++`?

Comment: Yes, i have. In vs2008 it works, on mac doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're practicing **c** try `fflush`, if c++ try `cout << endl;` each time you want to print.

Comment: I already tried endlines. No effect. I thought there was a simple way. Something like cout.flush() which also doesn't work. Oh well.

Comment: Hmm.. I think endl works after all. Probably magic. Thanks. I though it was something more serious.